# Command at startup or login

Tags: startup, scripts, command-line

I would like to run the following command after every boot (or login).

```
echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

It turns off my discrete GPU. To what script should I add this command.
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Looks about the same as the first related question: http://askubuntu.com/q/814/24102

Answer (score 2):

Instead of running a script you could install the package `sysfsutils` and add the line

```
kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch=OFF
```

to the file `/etc/sysfs.conf`

Answer (score 0):

You need root privileges to run that command, so you can add it to `/etc/rc.local` (but before the `exit 0` line) to have it run at the end of the boot process.

Otherwise you can add it to `/etc/gdm/PostLogin/Default` to have it run after any graphical login (when using GNOME GDM, default for Ubuntu *before* 11.10). If the file does not exist, just rename `/etc/gdm/PostLogin/Default.sample` and edit it.

Comment: i did that, but it doesn't work. I also tried to put "sleep 10" before the command, because i read somewhere it could be executed too early. do I just need to add the above mentioned line or is there more to it?

Comment: @Garips you might want to check http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Vga_switcheroo and confirm that you have the necessary options enabled in the kernel and that the `/sys/kernel/debug` filesystem is mounted...

Comment: does the /etc/gdm/PostLogin/Default work with 11.10 ?

Comment: @Garips Likely not, as 11.10 is using LightDM, not GDM

Comment: i think the options should be enabled, otherwise the command would't work at all. but it does work when I run it manually in the terminal.

Comment: but why is the command not executed inside /etc/rc.local? Maybe I have to add something to the command. I only added the above mentioned line before the last line. and i tried to put "sleep 10" before the command. do I maybe add something to that?